# How to reorganise the values of a groupBy from the same table (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `Chats` table setup like this:

| ID | CHAT_GROUP_ID | MESSAGE | READ | CREATED_AT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uu-34uu5-6662 | hi1 | 1 | 2022-06-02 13:16:42 |
| 2 | uu-34uu5-6662 | hi2 | 1 | 2022-06-02 13:16:45 |
| 3 | uu-34uu5-6663 | hi3 | 0 | 2022-06-02 13:16:46 |
| 4 | uu-34uu5-6663 | hi4 | 0 | 2022-06-02 13:16:47 |
| 5 | uu-34uu5-6664 | hi5 | 0 | 2022-06-02 13:16:49 |

```
ID = int
CHAT_GROUP_ID = Varchat(some kind of UUID)
MESSAGE = String
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

- GROUP ALL THE CHAT_GROUP_ID with their own respective IDs.
- When all the CHAT_GROUP_ID are grouped, SUM all the READ AS SUM(IF(read = 0, 1, 0))
- Finally (and where I am struggling), always show only 1 MESSAGE but always the latest one.

I have am struggling so much on this unbelievable! How can I do this?

Comment: What version of MySql? Showing the latest message per group_id  is best done with a windowing function, but they are not available until MySql 8, which a lot of people still don't have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it to be done in MySQL v5.*, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT tab.ID,
       tab.CHAT_GROUP_ID,
       tab.MESSAGE,
       aggregated.SUM_READ_,
       aggregated.MAX_TIME
FROM       tab 
INNER JOIN (SELECT CHAT_GROUP_ID,
                   SUM(IF(READ_=0,1,0)) AS SUM_READ_,
                   MAX(CREATED_AT)      AS MAX_TIME
            FROM tab
            GROUP BY CHAT_GROUP_ID             ) aggregated
        ON tab.CHAT_GROUP_ID = aggregated.CHAT_GROUP_ID
       AND tab.CREATED_AT = aggregated.MAX_TIME
```

First you create a view containing aggregated value of `READ` and `CREATED_AT` with respect to `CHAT_GROUP_ID`, then use these information to retrieve the needed infos from the main table.

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pmVmNq1Seoarq2zJsWrjTA/0).

Comment: Thank you so much, trying both your solutions, please give me some time

Comment: Wow! Brilliant! I did not realised I could test it on that links, you are a king! Thank you so much!

Comment: fwiw, the windowing function option will tend to perform better and is not sensitive to ties in the same way as joining to the projection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming at least MySql 8:

```
SELECT  ct.Chat_Group_ID, ct.Message, 
    ( SELECT SUM(Case when read = 1 then 0 else 1 end) 
      FROM Chats ct2
      WHERE ct2.Chat_Group_ID = ct.Chat_Group_ID
    ) as Unread
FROM (
    SELECT Chat_Group_ID, Message
       , row_number() over (partition by Chat_Group_ID order by create_at desc) rn
    FROM Chats
) ct 
WHERE ct.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, trying both your solutions, please give me some time